# The following page url can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on MVC5 project. I've an index page which is auto generated.
when the user goes the index page and decide to delete a record that its id is 5 for example, it goes to the following url: /XYZ/Delete/5

When the user confirm the deletion, he is redirected to index page: /Roles_ModelFields

If the user clicked the back button he will be redirected to:/XYZ/Delete/5, which gives an error: The following page url can't be found: /XYZ/Delete/5

How can I redirect him to the index page instead of the delete page with the deleted record id.

Regards.

Comment: `"When the user complete deleting a record, it go back to the index page. [...] How can I redirect him to the index page?"` - It sounds like you're already doing that?  Can you clarify what the problem is?  Are you already successfully redirecting the user to the index or not?

Comment: I mean that when the user go the index page, which is auto generated, and decided to delete a record that its id is 5 for example, it goes to the following url: /XYZ/Delete/1
When the user confirm the deletion, he is redirected to index page: /Roles_ModelFields
If the user clicked the back button he will be redirected to:/Roles_ModelFields, which gives an error: The following page url can't be found: /XYZ/Delete/5

Comment: So you mean the link from the index page to the `Delete` action is using the wrong ID value?  (1 instead of 5 in the example you just described.)  That's not clear at all from the question.  Please clarify exactly what problem you're facing and what you're asking.  **Edit:** The more you edit that previous comment, the less clear the problem becomes.  So... The user is pressing the back button and re-sending a request?  If the record doesn't exist, I'd expect a 404 error.  Is your controller code returning a 404?  Maybe if you show your code that might clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well following your example.. if the user has **already** deleted the record, then redirected back to the Index page, and then the user decided to hit the back button then they should be presented with the error "The following page url can't be found".  That page cannot be found because that page is specifically for the record that you've deleted.

This is most likely not the best way to handle this situation, but in your Delete ActionResult.. I'm assuming you left the generic code in the action, so it looks like this:

```
// GET: ControllerName/Delete/5
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ...

    if(!db.TableName.Any(x => x.Id == id.Value)) // if there are zero record's Ids that match the id passed then do this
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.